# find 2d elements in a 3d array which are similar to 2d elements in another 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 3D arrays and want to identify 2D elements in one array, which have one or more similar counterparts in the other array.

This works in Python 3:

```
import numpy as np
import random

np.random.seed(123)
A = np.round(np.random.rand(25000,2,2),2)
B = np.round(np.random.rand(25000,2,2),2)

a_index = np.zeros(A.shape[0])

for a in range(A.shape[0]):
    for b in range(B.shape[0]):
        if np.allclose(A[a,:,:].reshape(-1, A.shape[1]), B[b,:,:].reshape(-1, B.shape[1]),
                       rtol=1e-04, atol=1e-06):
            a_index[a] = 1
            break

np.nonzero(a_index)[0]
```

But of course this approach is awfully slow. Please tell me, that there is a more efficient way (and what it is). THX.

Comment: my result is `array([ 1972,  7108, 13369, 14252, 23171], dtype=int64)` by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do an all-nearest-neighbor type query.  This is something that has special O(n log n) algorithms, I'm not aware of a python implementation.  However you can use regular nearest-neighbor which is also O(n log n) just a bit slower.  For example `scipy.spatial.KDTree` or `cKDTree`.

```
import numpy as np
import random
np.random.seed(123)
A = np.round(np.random.rand(25000,2,2),2)
B = np.round(np.random.rand(25000,2,2),2)

import scipy.spatial
tree = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(A.reshape(25000, 4))
results = tree.query_ball_point(B.reshape(25000, 4), r=1e-04, p=1)

print [r for r in results if r != []]
# [[14252], [1972], [7108], [13369], [23171]]
```

`query_ball_point()` is not an exact equivalent to `allclose()` but it is *close enough*, especially if you don't care about the `rtol` parameter to `allclose()`.  You also get a choice of metric (`p=1` for city block, or `p=2` for Euclidean).

P.S. Consider using `query_ball_tree()` for very large data sets.  Both A and B have to be indexed in that case.

P.S. I'm not sure what effect the 2d-ness of the elements should have; the sample code I gave treats them as 1d and that is identical at least when using city block metric.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of [`np.allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html), we have :

> If the following equation is element-wise True, then allclose returns
>   True.
>
> absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))

Using that criteria, we can have a vectorized implementation using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), customized for the stated problem, like so -

```
# Setup parameters
rtol,atol = 1e-04, 1e-06

# Use np.allclose criteria to detect true/false across all pairwise elements
mask = np.abs(A[:,None,] - B) <= (atol + rtol * np.abs(B))

# Use the problem context to get final output
out = np.nonzero(mask.all(axis=(2,3)).any(1))[0]
```